# How to open a log window for a game without using the executable's shortcut?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have been using a log window to find commands while playing the Unreal Engine game *Batman Arkham City*. Normally, I do this by adding the `-log` switch to a shortcut of the game.

I also use the Texmod modding program a lot when playing the game. The problem is, in order for Texmod to work correctly, you need to the launch the game through it. But then, if you do that, the log window won't appear.

What I'm looking for is a way to have a log window while playing the game even though I am launching it using Texmod.

Comment: I think this answers what you're asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406225/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-running-process-or-exe-by-default